# apache does not read .htaccess file on mac os lion

Tags: macos, .htaccess

Xampp does not read .htaccess file on MAC Lion.
I cannot run like this http://test.dev/blogs/test
It works only http://test.dev/

I just see log file

> 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2012:22:09:41 +0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12430

Comment: Whats in your `.htaccess` file? Is `AllowOverride` turned on in your `httpd.conf` and if so what are you allowed to override?

Comment: Yes, I allowed to override already but the result is the same.
My configuration:
   <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.dev">
      Options All MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from all

      #XAMPP
      Order deny,allow
      #Deny from all

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .htaccess files are readable by the process that is running apache, which you can check with

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```